# Unknown property received as parameter in React function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I am working on a simple React app that calculates a fee for listing an item for sale. I am using functional components and have created a custom hook called useItems() to track the data of items, total, and newItem.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import moment from 'moment';

const newItemConstructor = {
    itemType: -1,
    userType: -1,
    price: 100,
    endDate: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")
};

function useItems() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
    const [newItem, setNewItem ] = useState(newItemConstructor);

    return {
        items, setItems,
        total, setTotal,
        newItem, setNewItem
    };
}

export default useItems;
```

The values for these properties is updated using a form. I can see the values for newItem is updated as expected, but when I try to pass *newItem* as a parameter for the calculator to get the total fees I get an error: "Unknown user type"

This is where I'm calling the getFee() to calculate the fee using the calculator function. And you can see the form below.

```
import React from "react";
import { Calculator } from "./calculator";
import useItems from "./hooks/useItems";


function NewItemForm() {
  const {items, total, newItem, setItems, setTotal, setNewItem} = useItems();


  const onNewItemSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const calc = new Calculator();
    const fee = calc.getFee(newItem);  // Error: Unknown user type
    const itemTotal = setTotal(total + fee);

  };

  return ( 
    <div className="New-item-form">
        <h3>Register new item</h3>
        <form className="New-item-form" onSubmit={onNewItemSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
            <label>You are</label>
            <select
              className="form-control"
              id="userType"
              defaultValue="-1"
              onChange={(event) => {
                setNewItem({
                  ...newItem, 
                  userType: event.target.value
                })
            }}>
            <option value="-1">Select</option>
            <option value="0">Person</option>
            <option value="1">Company</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
            <label>Item Type</label>
            <select
              className="form-control"
              id="itemType"
              defaultValue="-1"
              onChange={(event) => {
                setNewItem({
                  ...newItem, 
                  itemType: event.target.value
                })
            }}>
            <option value="-1">Select </option>
            <option value="0">Auction</option>
            <option value="1">Buy it now</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="itemType">Price</label>
            <input 
              className="form-control" 
              type="number" 
              value={newItem.price} 
              onChange={(event) => {
                setNewItem({
                  ...newItem, 
                  price: event.target.value
                })
              }}/>
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="itemType">End date</label>
            <input 
              className="form-control" 
              type="text" 
              value={newItem.endDate} 
              onChange={(event) => {
                setNewItem({
                  ...newItem, 
                  endDate: event.target.value
                })
              }}/>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
   );
}
```

Calculator function:

```
import moment from 'moment';

export class Calculator {
  getFee({userType, itemType, price, endDate}) {    
    switch (userType) {
      case 0: //Normal
        if (itemType === 0) {
          //Auction
          let endDateDiscount = 0;
          const isToday = moment(endDate).isSame(moment(), 'day');
          if (isToday) {
            endDateDiscount = 10;
          }
          return price + 25 - endDateDiscount;
        } else if (itemType === 1) {
          //BuyItNow
          return price + 35 - 0;
        }
        break;
      case 1: //Company
        if (itemType === 0) {
          //Auction
          const isToday = moment(endDate).isSame(moment(), 'day');
          if (isToday) {
            return price + 25 - 15; // Enddate discount and company discount
          }

          return price + 25 - 5; // Only company discount
        } else if (itemType === 1) {
          //BuyItNow
          return price + 35 - 5;
        }
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error('Unknown user type');
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the correct values for newItem passed to the getFee function?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Show us the implementation of Calculator

Comment: @wxker I updated the main post with the calculator function. Thanks!